# C++ result of operator= changing after return *this

Tags: c++, templates, variable-assignment, operator-keyword, stdmove

Here, I have a very simple program that moves a value from one object to another, making sure to remove the value from the one that it was taken from (leaving behind a '0').

```
#include <iostream>

struct S
{
    S(char val) : m_val(val) {}
    S& operator=(S&& other) noexcept
    {
        this->m_val = other.m_val;
        other.m_val = '0';

        return *this;
    }
    char m_val = '0';
};

int main()
{
    S a('a');
    S b('b');

    std::cout << "a.m_val = '" << a.m_val << "'" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b.m_val = '" << b.m_val << "'" << std::endl;

    a = std::move(b);

    std::cout << "a.m_val = '" << a.m_val << "'" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b.m_val = '" << b.m_val << "'" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

As expected, the output of this program is:

```
a.m_val = 'a'
b.m_val = 'b'
a.m_val = 'b'
b.m_val = '0'
```

The value of 'b' is transferred from object b to object a, leaving a '0' behind.
Now, if I generalize this a bit more with a template to (hopefully) automatically do the move and delete business, here's what I end up with... (distilled down of course).

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct P
{
    P<T>& operator=(P<T>&& other) noexcept
    {
        T& thisDerived = static_cast<T&>(*this);
        T& otherDerived = static_cast<T&>(other);

        thisDerived = otherDerived;
        otherDerived.m_val = '0';

        return *this;
    }
protected:
    P<T>& operator=(const P<T>& other) = default;
};

struct S : public P<S>
{
    S(char val) : m_val(val) {}

    char m_val = '0';
};

int main()
{
    S a('a');
    S b('b');

    std::cout << "a.m_val = '" << a.m_val << "'" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b.m_val = '" << b.m_val << "'" << std::endl;

    a = std::move(b);

    std::cout << "a.m_val = '" << a.m_val << "'" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b.m_val = '" << b.m_val << "'" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When run, the output is:

```
a.m_val = 'a'
b.m_val = 'b'
a.m_val = '0'
b.m_val = '0'
```

Uh oh! Somehow BOTH objects got "deleted".  When I step through the body of the move assignment operator code... all seems well!  a.m_val is 'b' like we expect... right up until the `return *this;` statement.  Once it returns from the function, suddenly that value gets set back to '0'.
Can anybody please shed some light on why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
P<T>& operator=(P<T>&& other) noexcept
```

This is an explicit move assignment operator for this template class.

```
struct S : public P<S> {
```

This subclass inherits from this template class. `P<S>` is its parent class.

This subclass does not have an explicit move assignment operator, so your C++ compiler helpfully creates a default move assignment operator for you, because that's how C++ works. The default move-assignment operator invokes the parent class's move assignment operator, and the default move assignment operator then move-assigns all members of this class.

Just because the parent class has an explicit move assignment operator (your move assignment operator) doesn't make ***this*** child class's default move assignment operator disappear. `S`'s default move assignment operator is effectively this, ***very*** loosely speaking:

```
S &operator=(S &&other)
{
    P<S>::operator=(std::move(other));
    this->m_val=std::move(other.m_val);

    return *this;
}
```

That's what you get for free, from your C++ compiler. Isn't it nice of your C++ compiler to provide such a useful default move assignment operator for your class?

```
a = std::move(b);
```

This actually ends up invoking the above default move assignment operator.

Which first invokes the parent class's move assignment operator, the one you wrote.

Which effectively sets `other.m_val` to `'0'`.

And when it returns, this default move assignment operator also sets `this->m_val` to `'0'`.

Comment: Ah geeze... I can't believe I missed that!  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `S` has a [implicitly generated move assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment#Implicitly-defined_move_assignment_operator), which calls the move assignment operator of the base class (i.e. the `P<T>::operator=`), then perform member-wise move assignment on the members (i.e. `S::m_val`). In the `P<T>::operator=`, `other.m_val` has been assigned to `'0'`, then back to `S::operator=` `this->m_val` is assigned by `other.m_val` and becomes `'0'` too.

You can define a user-defined move assignment operator for `S` and does nothing expect calling the base class version. e.g.

```
struct S : public P<S>
{
    S(char val) : m_val(val) {}

    char m_val = '0';

    S& operator=(S&& other) {
        P<S>::operator=(other);
        return *this;
    }
};
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CRehaSScc2T25MJ3)

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone!  This, and Sam Varshavchik's answer below answered it for me. :)